# FlashChartHelper for OpenFlashChart2 in CakePHP: blank charts

Tags: linux, apache, cakephp, openflashchart2

So I have recently started playing with Ubuntu, PHP, and CakePHP and have been pretty happy with the LAMP stack.  Except now I'm trying to build a simple web page that can display collected data in a graph.  Apparently OpenFlashChart2 with the FlashChartHelper plugin is pretty good, but I cannot get it to actually display a graph.  I got the "hello world" sample described in the OpenFlashChart2 documentation to work, but when I try the FlashChartHelper samples I just get a blank spot where my graph is supposed to be.  There is no error message, just... nothing.  I verified that all the files are installed as listed on the page, and I made sure to define $helpers in my controller

var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Flash','FlashChart');

Could it be a pathing issue?  My webroot is /var/www/, but I unzipped cake into /var/www/www2/ .  The rest of my site, including entering data, works just fine.

Has anyone else seen this before?  What did you do to resolve the issue?  Failing that, can you recommend another graphing library?  Specifically, I need to render a scatter graph.  I have a collection of data points that are collected at irregular intervals.  Either suggestions on fixing FlashChartHelper or another library would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps take a look at this resource:

[http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2006/09/26/tutorial-integrating-phpswf-charts-with-cakephp/][1]

It seems to have everything you need?